# My Perforce Eclipse Plugin works only partially

Tags: eclipse-plugin, perforce

I installed Perforce plugin version 3.4 on Eclipse Ganymede, configured my connection and workspace. My perforce perspective works just fine. However, when I work in the Java perspective, and I right-click any file in the project explorer, the "Team" context menu does not display the perforce options to check-out, sync etc. It only has the options "Apply patch" and "Show local history".

This is super-annoying! Help, anyone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you right clicked on the project and done Team -> share Project -> Perforce (connection information?)

Also if the connection information was wrong, then in some versions of the plugin it does not complain. It just silently does not show you any options. A good check for this would to open the P4 Depot view inside the eclipse (Window -> Show View -> P4 connections)

Comment: Thanks for the info. This was bugging me for ages - now resolved :)

Answer (score 2):

Check the Java Perspective customization (from the [Window menu](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-60.htm)):

[image]

[image]

And see if there are any "Perforce"-related commands for you to activate.

(cf. the [Configuring perspective command groups](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-9m.htm))

> You can choose which **command groups** are available in a perspective.
>   Command groups contribute menu items, toolbar buttons and key bindings, all of which run commands.
>   Making a command group unavailable in a perspective removes these methods of running commands.
>   Making a command group available makes it possible for these methods to be used, however they can be turned on and off with more fine-grained control via the Menu Visibility and Tool Bar Visibility tabs of the Customize Perspective dialog